# Setting EFI vars for a GCE VM

Tags: google-compute-engine, uefi

I am trying to create a boot disk for a GCE VM from scratch. I am using

```
gcloud compute images create myimage --source-uri gs://mybucket/image.tar.gz
```

When setting up a bare  metal boot disk, I create an VFAR paritition containing `BOOT\EFI\BOOTX64.EFI` and then I tell the motherboard where to find that VFAT partition by writing efivars in NVRAM. This is usually done with `efibootmgr` or similar.

When creating a GCE VM from a custom disk image, do I have to set these EFI vars somewhere? If so, how do I set them before booting my VM? If not, how does GCE know which paritition to look in for the file `BOOT\EFI\BOOTX64.EFI`?

On bare metal, I would tell the motherboard where to find my EFI parition with:

```
efibootmgr \
    --bootnum 0000 \
    --disk /dev/nvme0n1 \
    --part 1 \
    --create \
    --label "Arch Linux" \
    --loader /vmlinuz-linux \
    --unicode "root=PARTUUID=b2cf7be8-03 resume=PARTUUID=b2cf7be8-03 rw initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux.img" \
    --verbose
```

How do I tell GCE this same information, or if that is unnecessary then how does GCE deduce this information?